# ODBC Authentication with .pem files on Ubuntu server with Python

Tags: ubuntu, python, mysql, ssl, odbc

Using the below 3 PEM files I am able to connected successfully to a MySQL database on windows threw setting up a Data Source. (No problems here)

- client-key.pem
- client-cert.pem
- ca-cert.pem

But I also want to be able to connect via Python code on an Ubuntu server 10.04. I have Python and the MySQL Python Connector setup. But as expected fails trying to connect with the credentials alone  since authorisation threw these PEM certificates are required.

```
**>>>** import mysql.connector
**>>>** cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='odbc_user', password='mypassword',host='00.00.000.000',database='mydb')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mysql/connector/__init__.py", line 179, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 95, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 719, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 210, in _open_connection
    self._ssl)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 144, in _do_auth
    self._auth_switch_request(username, password)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 177, in _auth_switch_request
    **raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'odbc_user'@'hide.ec2' (using password: YES)**
**>>>**
```

What I have tried based on searches but with no progress:

- Copied the 3 **.pem** files to **/usr/share/ca-certificates/** as **.crt** files.
- Ran  `sudo update-ca-certificates`which added these to the **/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt** file.

I'm no Linux guru and just trying anything I come across so if someone has done this before I would much appreciate the help.

Comment: According to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html (section "Connecting through SSL") all you need to do is pass the appropriate arguments to `mysql.connector.connect`.

Comment: My man. So obvious and easy once you know the answer. And I wasn't even looking at the Python itself as assumed I need to setup environment. Never considered passing the files with connection values.

Answer (score 0):

```
    >>>import mysql.connector
    >>>cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='odbc_user', password='password',host='00.00.00.000',database='database',
        ssl_ca='/home/akelly/ca-cert.pem',
        ssl_cert='/home/akelly/client-cert.pem',
        ssl_key='/home/akelly/client-key.pem')
```